# Google+ and comment dialog within iframe

Tags: iframe, google-plus

I have a Google+ fastbutton within an iframe of a page. When the button is hovered the "Publicly recommend this as ..." popup displays, but since the button is positioned at the right edge of the iframe the popup is getting cut off. I would like to force the popup to display to the left of the Google+ button but I don't see any information on how to do this or if it can even be done. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

**MYDOMAIN1.COM/parentpage.html:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <iframe src="http://mydomain2.com/myiframe.html"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    ....
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**MYDOMAIN2.COM/myiframe.html:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<iframe src="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1
    &bsv=o&size=tall&count=true&align=left&hl=en-US
    &origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain1.com
    &url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain1.com%2Fmypage%2F
    &parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain1.com" id="I0_1234567890123"
    name="I0_1234567890123" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no" data-gapiattached="true" title="+1">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The page on MYDOMAIN1.COM is a Wordpress PHP page. The iframe content at MYDOMAIN2.COM is an ASP application - thus the separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?...` is not a public API and you should not use it directly. Instead use the [documented +1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) which supports an `expandTo` parameter where you can position the bubbles in the direction you want.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
    <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="http://example.com" expandTo="bottom" ></div>

    <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: abraham, been out of town. Got back and included the example code in your answer, but nothing appears at all and no errors are apparent. This is getting loaded into a Wordpress page. I tried prepending `$` to `(function()`. That made no difference. Is there something you can think of that would cause the Google+ button not to appear at all?

Comment: abraham, I tried the <g:plusone> method of including the button and that worked fine. I don't really understand the differences, but I've tested it and all is well. Thank you for your answer.